# Retrieve data from a Firebase array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a simple Firebase project where I am supposed to save an array to Firebase and later retrieve as an array. I managed to save the array to the database but I can't manage to retrieve it and put it into an array.

[image]

This is the code I have come the farthest with but I still can't put it into an array

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("list").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            print(snapshot)

        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the value of a location to get the array.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("list")

ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if let objects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        print(objects)
    }
})
```

Comment: I only get the error "Cast from 'NSEnumerator' to unrelated type '[FIRDataSnapshot]' always fails". http://imgur.com/a/1TGur

Comment: Try `snapshot.children.allObjects`

Comment: Awesome, that solved it for me. My last problem is when I print it I get it as [Snap (0) test1, Snap (1) test2, Snap (2) test 3]. How do I do to get it as just [test1, test2, test 3]?

Comment: `print(objects.map { $0.value })`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all the help!